# Merging Branch into Trunk

Tags: svn

Now I know this has been asked a few times, but i'm still not getting it...

I use Versions which is doing a great job, I am also using beansalk and they are working nicely together. However, I have been working on a branch of the trunk (sandbox) which I now want to merge back into the trunk. Versions can't do this, so it's into Terminal.

Sandbox is reversion 256 and the Trunk (because of a few other amends) is 255.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, juste use the merge: svn merge -r N:M SOURCE [PATH]

Example:
$ svn merge -r 250:HEAD HTTP_OR_SSH_OR_SVN://path_to_your_local_or_network_repo

You may look here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re16.html

Comment: Tried:

svn merge -r 243:HEAD https://root_to_branch

But am getting:

svn: '.' is not a working copy

Comment: Are you running the command on the root of your project?
Ex.: If your project lives in /home/your_name/projects, you must run the command inside the projects directory (or in any subdir with a .svn folder :)

Answer (score 0):

**Araixs Merge** tool is best for such kind of issue you can merge your changes and the **check in** into **trunk**